# Zend_Validate::is() Static Check, get validation message work around

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

Does anyone know of a way to get validation messages from using Zend_Validate in static scope?

```
Zend_Validate::is($value, $validator[0], $validator[2])
```

The docs say explicitly that getting the messages isn't an option: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html#zend.validate.introduction.static

Slightly discouraging, but I was wondering if someone knew of any other methods that are inside Zend for getting messages from a validation string?

I'm following a great article about validating at the model level if anyone is interested: http://www.cambraca.com/2011/03/validation-in-zend-framework-model.html

Thanks for the help,
-Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it just cannot be done. See, the messages are attached to each Validator *object* - you cannot attach them to *class* (unless you make your own implementation of the validation logic with static message properties and static setter/getter for it and will use it instead).

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, the validator object used is lost once the function returns so there is no way to access it or its messages.

Comment: Dang, fair enough. Thanks for the confirmation.