# Zend_Validate::is - haw can I get the error message from it?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend_Validate::is() Static Check, get validation message work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370294/zend-validateis-static-check-get-validation-message-work-around)

I need a simple check for right email address. So I use `Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress');` But it return only "false" for the gmail.com addresses. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I mispelled part of the answer, the correct syntax is:

```
$value = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress; $value->isValid($the variable or string you want to check);
```

Comment: Yeah, had to do just that, static method isn`t usable at all

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax for a validation with Zend is 
    $value = new Zend_Validate_EmailAdress
    $value->isValid($the variable or string you want to check), 
that should return true for any email adress.